# Typescript default export undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing an npm module, a simple logger. I wrote this in plain JS:

**logger.js**

```
class Logger {
  // stuff
}

module.exports = Logger;
```

In a js script, this works fine:

**logger-test.js**

```
const Logger = require('ep-logger');

const logger = new Logger('my-logger');
logger.info('yo');
```

But we at our company use **TypeScript**. So next to my `logger.js` I created a file `logger.d.ts` which reads as follows

```
export interface SplunkOptions {
    endpoint?: string
    loggingSource?: string
    loggingSourceType?: string
}

export interface LoggerOptions {
    stage?: string
    level?: string
    splunk?: SplunkOptions
}

export default class Logger {
    constructor(name: string);

    public static setOptions(obj: LoggerOptions): void;

    public error(message: string | Error, ...data: any[]): void;
    public warn(message: string | Error, ...data: any[]): void;
    public info(message: string | Error, ...data: any[]): void;
    public verbose(message: string | Error, ...data: any[]): void;
    public debug(message: string | Error, ...data: any[]): void;
    public silly(message: string | Error, ...data: any[]): void;
}
```

In my `package.json` I did this:

```
{
  // more package.json stuff here
  "main": "src/logger.js",
  "types": "src/logger.d.ts"
}
```

Now in my *TypeScript*-Project I am trying to use my logger:

**index.ts**

```
import Logger from 'ep-logger';

const logger: Logger = new Logger('my-logger');
logger.info('yo');
```

But I get an error that my logger does not have a default export:

> { Error: Command failed: ts-node local-lambda.ts --colors
>
> /Users/luke/Arbeit/WeltN24/Editorial Products/projects/ep-logger-tests/js-app/yo-lambda/src/index.ts:5
>     const logger: Logger = new Logger('my-logger');
>                            ^
>   TypeError: ep_logger_1.default is not a constructor
>   ...

In fact, if I do

```
console.log(Logger);
```

I get

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

With current version of typescript (2.6 or below), you need to write your definition file with [export assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) instead of default export:

```
export interface SplunkOptions {
    //...
}

export interface LoggerOptions {
    //...
}

export class Logger {
    //...
}

export = Logger;
```

[It seems like the plan is to change all that in the next version](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19675) (2.7), and the way you have it written originally will start working (breaking `export =` in the process), initially behind the `--strictESM` flag, then, starting from 2.8, as default behavior without any flags.